# BOOT_COMPLETED is not getting called in device

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-reboot

i want to start an alram when the device gets boot, for that i have done following stuff

1) User permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2) add receiver with intent action in manifest file

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".sms.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

3) source

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager dayAlarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent dayAlarmIntent;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "FIRED BOOT COMPLETE" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
    }
}
```

above code is working in genymotion but not on a real device

Comment: do you a custom rom on your device ?

Comment: and what about if You delete the if statement and just check if the Boradcast is received?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs why? It isn't the problem.

Comment: only wanted to know if BroadcastReceiver does not receive or just the statement isn´t fired....

Comment: BroadcastReceiver doesnt receive it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for helping out but finally i was able to make it work `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` by setting `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` as boot complete fires for application those are stored in internal memory.

Comment: Worked for me . check the link for the details for why to use  android:installLocation="internalOnly"   
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location#ShouldNot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `android:name=".sms.BootReceiver"`, it should be `android:name=".BootReceiver"`. But some devices don't catch `BOOT_COMPLETED`. Your `intent-filter` should be like following:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
   <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
</intent-filter>
```

And don't forget to edit your source:

```
if ((intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") 
   || intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON")
   || intent.getAction().equals("com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"))){
      Toast.makeText(context, "FIRED BOOT COMPLETE" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i have tried your solution , but this thing gets called only when my device automatically gets rebooted i.e. when my device goes out of battery and switched off.

Comment: @Hunt in my opinion, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What in the world is **com.htc.intent.**?

Answer (score 0):

```
  android:name=".sms.BootReceiver"
```

instead of that use

```
android:name=".BootReceiver"
```

Or

```
android:name="complete.packagename.sms.BootReceiver"
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: i have tried your solution , but this thing gets called only when my device automatically gets rebooted i.e. when my device goes out of battery and switched off

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have atleat one activity present in your Application.From Android 3.1, BroadcastReceiver will not work until the user has manually launched an activity, This is for provide security . once the user runs the app for the first time then your BroadcastReceiver will run always except it does not Force Stop it. Once activity launch at first time your broadcast receiver will run even after reboot your deice.

On emulator it is working- It may be because it is running on lower version than 3.1 and real device run on higher than 3.1

Comment: i have tried that after rebooting i opened my activity then again reboot it but still its not getting called and my emulator has a 4.2 version

Comment: What happens when the device reboots?

Answer (score -1):

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.example.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```